# JDBC realm not finding the mysql driver

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat

I am using eclipse for my dynamic web project..

I need a log in page for my website. I gave the following configuration in server.xml :

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
                driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Chat?user=root&amp;password=public"
                userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="password" />

</Realm>
```

I have set the `mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar` in the `java build path/libraries`

When I run the program I get the following error :

```
SEVERE: Exception opening database connection
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:644)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.startInternal(JDBCRealm.java:715)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:245)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:937)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:640)
... 19 more
```

But finally the server is started up...when I try to login from the login page this error is displayed again..

MySQL version is 8.0.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you are saying, It looks like you are missing Mysql driver jar in your classpath.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:640)
```

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-how-to-solve-class-not-found-exception/

Can you try manually copying the jar in `<Webappdir>/web-inf/lib` ?